# Check if flyback transformers are working

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, flyback

I recently got 3 flyback transformers for $21 at a store which are all different. They were most likely harvested from old TVs. However I am not sure if they are still functioning. I tried to test by connecting around 15v from 4 cells to the wire that is supposed to output the rectified DC voltage(the one with a suction cup), and measuring the voltage between the negative and the pins but none gave a significant voltage (none above 0.1v). All the transformers acted this way. Are they all broken? Are there any other ways of telling.

My setup was similar to this:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=CXxkOQOK_uA

Comment: You need to apply AC to the proper terminals. But be careful - they might create a high voltage inductive kick if you apply DC current and then break the circuit.

Comment: @PStechPaul do I need AC for even if I am not trying to drive it? I am just trying to find the other end of the secondary coil.

Comment: I see from the video and the comments that the method shown is needed to forward bias the integral high voltage diode. It is actually several diodes in series, so it will be several volts. Try reversing polarity. If no joy, the flybacks may be defective or damaged. The rectifier, or the coil, may be open.

Comment: @PStechPaul , thx I am getting much larger voltages but they are still all under 1v